# Editing the info.plist file via config.xml in phonegap app?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I'm using this Facebook plugin:

https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

It requires to add the following code to the `info.plist` file for iOS use.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fb45656565656561</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>45656565656561</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>APP-NAME</string>
```

And

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

I'm using Phonegap build so i can only edit the `info.plist` file using the `config.xml` file...

I did search on how to edit the `info.plist` file via config.xml in phonegap app project and found a few but they are all about the camera plugin...

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found it:

```
 <platform name="ios">
 <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="CFBundleURLTypes">
    <array>
        <dict>
          <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
          <array>
            <string>45656565656561</string>
            <string>APP-NAME</string>
          </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</config-file>
</platform>
```

Add this to your `config.xml` file.

I hope this will help others in the future as this seems to be the only question/answer on this topic for this particular cordova plugin.